# How to work with multiple levels of abstractions with Entity Framework and code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have an existing model with multiple levels of inheritence with several of the intermediate classes being abstract.  The model looks fine, but when trying to create the database I get the error:

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 13, 20:Two entities with different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with different keys to the same group of rows.

Here's the simplest code I could write to reproduce the error.  If I make `Pet` concrete, the problem goes away.  What I can I do to allow multiple abstract classes in my hierarchy?

```
public abstract class Animal
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
public abstract class Pet : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Fish : Pet
{
    public bool IsFreshwater { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
    public bool IsNeutered { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Animal
{
    public Pet MyPet { get; set; }
}

public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class AnimalTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CanCreateDatabase()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PersonContext>());
        using (var context = new PersonContext())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(0, context.People.Count());//fails here
        }
    }
}
```

Update.  Here's a KDiff snap of the differences in the generated .edmx file.  The file on the left is my original code that fails and on the right is what is generated when I include a `DbSet<Pet>` in my DbContext.
[image: KDiff of edmx differences]

Comment: What type of configuration are you targeting here?  There are two types.  Table per type, table per hierarchy.  Which are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Table per hierarchy.  Performance is essential.

Comment: The fact that it works with a *concrete* but not an *abstract* `Pet` lets me suspect that this is a bug. Did you try to make `Animal` an entity, for example by adding a `DbSet<Animal>` to your context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Pets to your context:

```
// Table-per-class (TPC)
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: I just saw your comment where you stated you wanted table by hierarchy inheritance.  Your problem, then, is that your DbSet is not typed properly - you want a single DbSet using the base type:

```
// Table-per-hierarchy (TPH)
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I much prefer the database structure produced by using a DbSet of People.  Your first answer gives the result I need, but it's not clear why this helps.

Comment: Would appreciate marked as answered, then ;)

As for why - EF needs to compile your POCOs and DbContext class and create the mappings to the DB.  Person references Pet, but you don't have a Pet DbSet in the context, so my theory is EF gets confused as  to how to map Pet to the DB.

Comment: I still don't exactly understand what is happening here, but your answer works for me because I don't have to change my entities and I still get the database that I want.